# Trying to insert PNGs over certain image, scaled down to fit at center left position

Tags: windows, batch-file, imagemagick, png, mogrify

I'm using Windows and I can't figure out how to batch insert images over a particular background image.

Here's what I'm trying to do:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/IPDuP.jpg

Here's the background image alone (1280x390):
https://i.stack.imgur.com/w9kvi.jpg

Here's the folder with the several hundreds of images I would like to combine (each file is much larger so must fit in height with the same aspect ratio):
https://i.stack.imgur.com/qAqKt.jpg

Any help would be greatly appreciated (I am using Windows).

Comment: I suggest that you start with reading [ImageMagick Command-line Tools](https://imagemagick.org/script/command-line-tools.php). I think, nobody will read the documentation about usage of ImageMagick from the command line for you to find out with which options `magick.exe` must be called for the image processing wanted by you. Once you know how the image processing can be done with `magick.exe` on a single image file, open a command prompt window and run `for /?` for help on this [Windows command](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/windows-commands).

Answer (score 1):

The command for resizing a single foreground image to 360px high and compositing in the bottom-left of a background image will be something like:

```
magick FOREGROUND.PNG -resize x360 BACKGROUND.PNG +swap -gravity southwest -composite RESULT.PNG
```

Experiment with that, then follow @Mofi 's fine advice about looking up the documentation about FOR loops.